# Different version of scala lib in build path and scala-ide

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have two versions of scala  (2.11.4 and 2.10.4). Currently I work on project based on scala 2.10. I've changed version in project properties but ide still complains about it:

> The version of scala library found in the build path (2.10.4.) is different from the one provided by scala IDE (2.11.4.). Make sure you know what you are doing.

I am using

> Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
>   Build id: 4.0.0-vfinal-20141216-1226-Typesafe

Project config:
[image]

Any idea how fix that?

Answer (score 1):

That complaint is a warning, not an error; all is fine. I suspect the message is mostly left over from when scala-ide used to only support working with a single version of scala in a single install (which was only fixed in 4.0)

Comment: Nope. In this instance (the major version is different, so there is a binary-incompatibility), this project needs to be configured for it to work.

Comment: When correctly configured, you still get this warning.

Comment: I attached screen from project configuration.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the warning?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the multiple scala version support, as described in [this blog post](http://scala-ide.org/blog/scala-installations.html).

Once correctly configured, as you showed in the image, this is just a warning and therefore safe to ignore.